# Cannot assign to property: 'width' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am new to Swift. I am getting this error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'width' is a get-only property

While using this statement:

```
 cell.reciverMsg.frame.width = cell.reciverMsg.text?.characters.count * 2
```

`reciverMsg` is an `UILabel`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set the `width` of the frame's `size` property.

```
cell.reciverMsg.frame.size.width = 20
```

The `width` property of `frame` is just a read-only convenience. See the documentation for `CGRect` for details.